# What must be done to migrate from Storyboard back to XIBs for iOS 4.x support?

Tags: ios4, ios5, migration, storyboard, xib

I have seen scattered information related to this subject across stackoverflow and other sites, but nothing comprehensive.  I've wasted hours upon hours trying to get this to work to no avail.  However, I see in this post on stackoverflow (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7909906/extracting-nibs-xibs-from-storyboards-ios), but nothing with step by step details.

I have only a single view controller (HomeViewController) in my storyboard, and it is extended from a navigation controller.

Can someone please help me identify exactly what all needs to happen to make this work?

Please correct me, add to, etc to make these steps correct:

1. Create a new XIB (say, HomeViewController.xib)
2. Copy all items from the storyboard's view controller into this xib
3. Set the Class type for the view controller to be HomeViewController class.
4. Hook up all of the IBOutlets and IBActions.
5. ?? - Should I make the xib contain a navigation controller which contains the UIViewController, or should I set the File's Owner to the HomeViewController class??
6. Add new Window property in the AppDelegate class.
7. Create a new MainWindow.xib. What setup needs to happen here? (a) File's Owner to UIApplication; (b) Drag new Object to the "Objects" panel and set it's class to my AppDelegate class; (c) Drag new Window to the "Objects" panel; (d) Connect the IBOutlet for the AppDelegate Window property to this new window object.
8. Go to the project settings (click on the project in the Project Navigation tab, select the target), and clear the "Main Storyboard" field and set the Main Interface to what?  HomeViewController? Or Main Window?
9. Make the change in the AppDelegate class as shown below:

> ```
> - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
> {
>     //self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
>     // Override point for customization after application launch.
>     //self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
>
>     [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
>     return YES;
> }
> ```

This is all I know to do, but it still doesn't work.  What am I missing?

Comment: Hi @thephatp if you got any solution than please share with me..thanks.