# iOS storyboard back to viewcontroller.xib files

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard

after using storyboard in my project, I decide to go back to each of the viewcontroller having  its own xib. reasons:
1. when project has many scenes and viewcontroller, open one storyboard file in xcode is extremely slow no matter how fast your computer is.

2. it just doesnt get any benefit on overview when you have huge projects.
3. editing is suck. moving ui elements within the some views. it just pain in the ass experience ever.

so my question, how to convert back storyboard to every single viewcontroller xib files, just wanna know if there is automatic way to do so.

Comment: You do know you can have multiple storyboards in an application? You don't have to have all your controllers in the same one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extracting nibs/xibs from storyboards (iOS)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7909906/extracting-nibs-xibs-from-storyboards-ios)